# "Unknown user name or bad password" in specific Client, Server combination

Tags: windows, rdp

i have problems logging in specific client, server combinations.
Destination servers are all from a domain. Let's call it "Destination Domain".
Login via RDP from most clients to this servern in the destination Domain with an AD User from that domain work fine.
But when i try to login from the domain controllers of another domain (let's call it "source domain"), i am receiving the error: (only part of the security log on the destination Server)

```
An account failed to log on.
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A
```

This is with the same AD User, which whom login from different clients (even other clients from the source domain, which are not DCs in source domain) is working fine.

The user/domain/password is definitely not the problem. I checked the writing multiple times. I do copy username/domain/password from Passwordsafe and check the spelling before trying to connect.
The user is also not locked.

There are no saved credential in the Credential Manager on the clients. In the logs on the server the correct login user/domain is stated, but the login failes.

Also, it was previously possible to login to those servers in the destination domain from these clients (DCs in source domain).

I can not figure out, what the problem could be.
Does anybody have any

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on your Active Directory architecture? Is there a trust between source domain and destination domain? Or was there a trust, which is not working. The domain controllers are in source domain right?

Comment: By the way way from a security perspective I don't think it's a good idea to logon from a domain controller to another domain. Is source domain is compromised then using lateral movement it's easier for an threat actor to compromise both domains.